# How to animate an image sequence texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to create an animated texture, in this case a lava flowing look on a static mesh.
The 'lava' only consist of 10 frames atm, the texture animation would be looped.

However I have come across several problems.

- the textures doesn't update/animate when the i press play?
- how to keyframe this? can't seem to keyframe the nodes?
- it's suppose to loop when I tick the cyclic option? Doesn't seem to loop.

[image]
here is a screenshot of the settings i used on the image node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate the number of frames you want to be used for the sequence:

[image]

From the [documentation here:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/image_settings.html)

> Frames
>
> ```
> Sets the range of frames to use.
> ```